# Issue with ros::Time when using /use_sim_time

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, time, use-sim-time, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have the following issue that ros::Time::now()` always returns zero using the following minimum example.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      ros::init(argc, argv, "force_test_trajectory_pub");     // create ROS node
      while(ros::ok())  {
            beginTime = ros::Time::now();
            ROS_INFO("Starting time %f", beginTime.toSec());
      }
}
```

The following things are running propperly:

- I first start `roscore` as usual
- Then I set the parameter `/use_sim_time` to true
- Then I run gazebo using `rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo` to get a clock published on `/clock`
- Then I run the example above but which only outputs 0 even though /clock is constantly publishing

When I pause Gazebo, the while loop stops as well, which means synchronization is working in some way.

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328075/issue-with-ros::time-when-using-/use_sim_time/) by [JaFeKl](https://answers.ros.org/users/34185/jafekl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-09**:
Can you please update your question so that it includes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That way we don't have to add code to get your example to work (as-is, it won't compile).

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-09**:
Also, *how* are you setting `/use_sim_time` to `true`? Please include all of the commands that you run instead of paraphrasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest to add something of a sleep or `ros::Rate` in that `while` loop.

And a `ros::spinOnce()`: this is C++, subscriptions are only processed when the queues are spinned.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1